# How does Pengin die in the fight with Emonzaemon?

Tags: katanagatari

[image]

At the end of the fight between [Souda Emonzaemon](http://katanagatari.wikia.com/wiki/Emonzaemon_S%C5%8Dda) and [Maniwa Pengin](http://katanagatari.wikia.com/wiki/Pengin_Maniwa) in the [episode 11](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=270971), Emonzaemon starts firing random directions with [Entou Juu](http://katanagatari.wikia.com/wiki/Ent%C5%8D_J%C5%AB), and somehow a bullet reaches Pengin's body to kill him. I don't understand how this happened. Even when Emonzaemon fired directly towards Pengin, none of the bullets reached him because of his extremely high luck. Then, how was Emonzaemon able to shoot him by firing random directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the novel, when Emonzaemon shot his bullets off all over the room, he was aiming for things made of metal, like the nails on the floorboards and columns in the room.

As his bullets ricocheted off metal objects, Penguin's luck was forced to be pitted against the luck of the metal itself, which Penguin lost out to.

This was explained that no matter how lucky Penguin was, his luck would not last forever, because like all humans, he will one day have to die. Metal, on the other hand, has a much longer natural life span, far longer than that of humans. Therefore the metal has accumulated much more luck over the centuries, if not millennia, far surpassing the natural luck of any given human gathered in their lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

He ricochets the bullets off of his other ninpo, the blue ball he sent bouncing around the room.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Please consider expanding your answer. We want good, detailed answers, and not one-liners. Happy answering! :)